# В чём отличие Sliding Menu от Navigation Drawer?

Tags: android, android-navigation-drawer, sliding-menu

Насколько я понимаю, и то, и другое - выплывающее, как правило, с левой стороны боковое меню. В чём тогда отличие этих терминов?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Sliding Menu - сдвигает основной контент, находится на одной позиции по Z оси
2. Navigation Drawer - перекрывает основной контент, находится выше по Z оси